# Firebase initialize app dynamically depending of selected project

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is there a good way to `.initializeApp()` in Firebase **based on selected project** `$firebase use my-project-id`?

I find it prone to errors to have to manually change my code from DEV to QA to PROD. :)

From the console I have set environment configuration:

```
$ firebase functions:config:set my-project-dev.dbconnection.serviceaccountfile=myproject-dev-123.json
$ firebase functions:config:get
{
  "my-project-dev": {
    "databaseconnection": {
      "serviceaccountfile": "myproject-dev-123.json"
    }
  }
}
```

I have selected a project:

```
$ firebase use my-project-dev
```

In my code I would like to get the name of the currently selected project and load config accordingly:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const functions = require('firebase-functions')

const environmentConfig = process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG
const projectId = environmentConfig.projectId
const databaseURL = environmentConfig.databaseURL

const serviceAccountFile = `./${functions.config()[projectId].databaseconnection.serviceaccountfile}`  

const serviceAccount = require(serviceAccountFile)

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: databaseURL
}, 'myProjectHere')

const database = admin.database(app)

module.exports = database
```

This, however does not work since this is a catch 22 scenario. :)
I cannot read projectId from `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` before I have initialised the app. But I need the projectId for app initialisation `admin.initializeApp()`

What approach should be used to automatically select variables for `admin.initializeApp()` based on the selected project `firebase use my-project-dev`?

Many thanks! /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloud Functions you don't have to specify the configuration file in your code at all. From the documentation on [importing the required modules and initializing an app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app):

> ```
> // The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
> const functions = require('firebase-functions');
>
> // The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
> const admin = require('firebase-admin');
> admin.initializeApp();
> ```

This code already does implicitly what you're trying to do implicitly: it reads the configuration data for the active project (when run locally), or from the environment its on (when deployed).

Comment: Wow! Thank you @Frank for another prompt reply! That worked as a charm! Also, it makes 90% of my code redundant - which is a good thing. I cannot remember why I initialised the app and db that way in the first place. :) Also - I just realised that firebase functions:config:set is done for EACH project, not globally! :D